# Как называются такие схемы и как их читать?

Tags: javascript, блок-схема

Здравствуйте! Читаю книгу Крокфорда "Javascript. Сильные стороны". Там повсеместно используются схемы, как в приложении. Никогда ранее не встречался с такими. Есть как простые (в 1 линию), так и сложные (на пол страницы).

Спасибо за ответы![image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Это "синтаксическая схема", так же называемая "железнодорожной диаграммой"; используется для описания синтаксиса. Встречал краткое описание оной в книге Пратта и Зелковица "Языки программирования. Разработка и реализация".

Каждая "развилка пути" означает альтернативу. Тут, очевидно, описание "пробельного символа", который

1. либо пробел;
2. либо табуляция;
3. либо знак конца строки;
4. либо "//" за которым опционально следуют любые символы, завершающиеся концом строки (однострочный комментарий);
5. либо "/*" за которым следуют любые символы, и завершается все это "*/" (многострочный комментарий).

Comment: Спасибо за ответ (не могу ставить+)! Не могли бы посоветовать источник в сети для ознакомления?

Comment: Все, что нашлось на русском языке, вот: http://www.intuit.ru/studies/courses/26/26/lecture/801?page=7. Совсем кратко, но общий смысл после ознакомления с формой Бэкуса-Наура, думаю, должен быть понятен.

Answer (score 3):

Такие схемы используются ещё в документации к sqlite, оттуда может лучше станет понятно как их читать, на примерах базового синтаксиса SQL. к примеру SELECT: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html

P.S. это скорее не ответ, а дополнение к первому ответу, комментарий к сожалению не могу добавить.